# Item height relative to actual row height with * WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfApplication3="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="147*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="112*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TabControl Grid.Row="1">
            <TabItem Header="Match Bets" >

                <StackPanel Margin="15" Orientation="Vertical" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" >
                    <Label Content="My Header"/>
                    <DataGrid 
                        Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn  IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding Subject}" Header="Original A"  Width="Auto" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn  IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding PriceOriginalSelectionB}" Header="Original B"  Width="Auto" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn  IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding PriceDerivedSelectionA}" Header="Derived A"  Width="Auto" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn  IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding PriceDerivedSelectionB}" Header="Derived B"  Width="Auto" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>

                        <wpfApplication3:Dummy Subject="Subject 1" Body="Body 1" />
                        <wpfApplication3:Dummy Subject="Subject 2" Body="Body 2" />
                        <wpfApplication3:Dummy Subject="Subject 2" Body="Body 2" />
                        <wpfApplication3:Dummy Subject="Subject 2" Body="Body 2" />
                        <wpfApplication3:Dummy Subject="Subject 2" Body="Body 2" />
                        <wpfApplication3:Dummy Subject="Subject 2" Body="Body 2" />

                    </DataGrid>

                </StackPanel>

            </TabItem>

        </TabControl>
        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I want my datagrid (which is inside a stackpanel) only to grow to below the size of the row it is inside, but the stack panel seems to allow it to grow to any size it wants. Is there anyway without explicitly setting the height of the stack panel that I can do this. Or can I set the height of the stackpanel to be slightly smaller that the star * height of the row.

If I remove the stackpanel that the datagrid is inside this works fine, but I need the stackpanel to add other things above and below the datagrid.

Comment: your question is confusing, but I guess you want to set a `Margin` on the datagrid

Comment: you can use a `Grid` instead a `StackPanel`. Is `StackPanel` mandatory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a grid.  StackPanel behaves differently and Grid should allow "growing" as you want it.

Answer (score 2):

Do not set the `Height` of the DataGrid, but instead set the `VerticalAlign` to `Stretch`, and use a 5px top/bottom margin.